# How to insert a backspace in a string in C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, cpu-word, backspace

Is it possible to insert a backspace at the end of a string in C#?

If possible, then how do I insert a backspace in a string?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Take a look at Escape sequences: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Answer (score 13):

The escape sequence for backspace is:

```
\b
```

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cf2e3220-dc8d-4de7-96d3-44dd93a52423/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

> C# defines the following character escape sequences:
>
> - \' - single quote, needed for character literals
> - \" - double quote, needed for string literals
> - \\ - backslash
> - \0 – Null
> - \a - Alert
> - \b - Backspace
> - \f - Form feed
> - \n - New line
> - \r - Carriage return
> - \t - Horizontal tab
> - \v - Vertical quote
> - \u - Unicode escape sequence for character
> - \U - Unicode escape sequence for surrogate pairs.
> - \x - Unicode escape sequence similar to "\u" except with variable length.

Answer (score 5):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve. To simply remove the last character you could use this:

```
string originalString = "This is a long string";
string removeLast = originalString.Substring(0, originalString.Length - 1);
```

That `removeLast` would give **This is a long strin**

Answer (score 2):

this will insert a backspace in the string

```
string str = "this is some text";
Console.Write(str);
Console.ReadKey();
str += "\b ";
Console.Write(str);
Console.ReadKey();
//this will make "this is some tex _,cursor placed like so.
```

if its like Belogix said(to remove last char),you can do like belogix did or other way like:

```
string str = "this is some text";
Console.WriteLine(str);
Console.ReadKey();

Console.WriteLine(str.Remove(str.Length - 1,1));
Console.ReadKey();
```

or just:

```
string str = "this is some text";
Console.WriteLine(str + "\b ");
```